# Flask and chaquopy

Tags: python, java, android

I am looking at possibilities to run Python scripts in Android apps. I found two related terms but I'm not sure what is the difference between them and whether they even are the most appropriate for using Python in Android apps. Would you mind clarifying the difference between technologies and advice what is the most useful way to write Python code and use it in Android apps?

Chaquopy seems to be used for running Python script within Android apps and Flask sort of does the same?

Answer (score 0):

The two projects are not related:

- Chaquopy is for running Python on Android.
- Flask is for writing web servers in Python.

If you want, you can use them together to get a web server on Android.